# Как оптимизировать запрос?

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Как оптимизировать такой запрос?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT CONCAT_WS(user_id, rec_id) as id FROM messages WHERE user_id = МОЙ_ID OR rec_id = МОЙ_ИД) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

P.S. Такой запрос я не проверял, мне просто нужно узнать, его можно как-то по-другому реализовать?

Comment: IMHO в [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) первый аргумент д.б. *сепаратором*.

Вообще же, без знания структуры всех Ваших таблиц и понимания задачи в целом, что-либо посоветовать не удастся.

Comment: Откажитесь от *, если вам действительно не нужны все данные. Но даже если и нужны, перечисление необходимых полей повышает читабельность и избавляет от выборки ненужных данных в будущей, если они появятся.

Comment: >Такой запрос я не проверял, мне просто нужно узнать, его можно как-то по-другому реализовать?

Прозреваю, тестовое задание.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем запросе в качестве аргументов первичные ключи указываются. Запрос не получится оптимизировать. Посмотрите командой explain перед запросом.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.* FROM users, messages 
  WHERE ? IN (messages.user_id, messages.rec_id) AND id = CONCAT_WS(messages.user_id, messages.rec_id)
  ORDER BY id DESC;
```